# Wie heißt in einer Zahnarztpraxis der Angestellte, der Kundentermine und Bezahlungen behandelt?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Es gibt den Arzt, die Krankenschwester/Behandlungsassistenten, aber oft auch eine "Sekretärin" die am Telefon antwortet, usw.

Wie aber heißt die Funktion im Titel der Frage genannte Berufsbezeichnung?

Ich brauche es, um mein Lebenslauf auszufüllen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dieser Beruf wird im Deutschen als

> Zahnmedizinische Verwaltungsangestellte *(weiblich)*

bzw.

> Zahnmedizinischer Verwaltungsangestellter *(männlich)*

bezeichnet.

Einfachere Bezeichnungen sind u. a. *Sekretär(in) in einer Zahnarztpraxis*. *Zahnarzthelfer(innen)* wäre auch möglich; der Begriff beinhaltet dann aber evtl. auch einfache zahnmedizinische Tätigkeiten.

Comment: "Zahnarzthelferin" passt hier am besten, danke.

Comment: @patraulea: seit 2001 heißt die *"Zahnarzthelferin"* offiziell in Deutschland [Zahnmedizinische Fachangestellte](http://www.bzaek.de/nc/berufsstand/praxispersonal.html) und in der Schweiz [Zahnarztassistentin](http://www.ausbildung-weiterbildung.ch/zahnarztassistentin-info.html).

Comment: @Takkat Was nicht heißt, dass sie so heisst ;) Ich denke, *Zahnartzthelferin* fürfte noch eine ganze Weile besser passen...

Comment: @tofro: es ging um die Berufsbezeichung im Lebenslauf. Da sollte man grundsätzlich immer die offizielle Berufsbezeichung angeben, auch wenn sich diese im Volksmund noch nicht durchgesetzt hat (und wegen ihrer Sperrigkeit wohl auch nie durchsetzen wird).

Comment: Korrigierter Link https://www.bzaek.de/praxisteam/zahnmedizinischer-fachangestellter.html